# JSFL how to pass a variable to an existing texfield on stage

Tags: jsfl

Hi I'm try to do my personal extension if flash using JSFL.
this panel will have a button that run the jsfl code, the code read a value from a selected item on stage, how can i send this value to an existing texfield (or component) on the stage in my panel? The textfiled is a Dynamic text  named "val" (I set this name in property panel istance name field)
Here the jsfl code:

```
var element = fl.getDocumentDOM().selection[0]; 
var name = element.skewY;
var value = name;
val = name;
fl.trace(name);

fl.outputPanel.clear();
```

Any help?

Thank a lot
Luca

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method "setTextString(content)".
Like this:

```
element.setTextString(value);
```